# Cordova: How can I ensure that deviceReady and document.ready have fired?

Tags: cordova

I am working on a Cordova app which needs to get some data by an jquery Ajax call right at the start in order to get some information about the user. To identify the user I am using the device plugin with its uuid (I know that the uuid might change in certain cases).

When I try to put the database call in the deviceReady event nothing happens and if I put the database call in a document.ready event in the index.html the device id is not set.

Is there any way to ensure that both deviceReady and document.ready have fired before I do the database call?

Thanks in advance!

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {

    app.server = "http://xxx";
    $.ajaxSetup({
        dataType: "json",
        error: function(json) {alert(JSON.stringify(json)) }
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){

      document.addEventListener("deviceready",this.onDeviceReady,false);       
    });
},


onDeviceReady: function() {
    $.ajax({
          url: app.server + "userData/" + device.uuid,
          method: "get",
          success:function(json) {
            alert(json["user_id"]);
            //do other stuff
        }
        });
}
};
```

Comment: you're almost there; ensuring events have triggered will consist of two subsequential checks - first of the window load state, second of the device readiness. just try and replace the dom-ready check with a `window.load` listener.

Answer (score 0):

1) move the device ready event listener definition
outside of $(document).ready.

2) have two global variables:

```
var deviceIsReady = false;
var documentIsReady = false;
```

set the relevant value to true in the relevant function

3) at the end of each function test for

```
if (deviceIsReady && documentIsReady){doAjaxWork()}
```